# Code formatting script / Pretty Printer - PHP, JavaScript, jQuery, HTML

Tags: unix, printing, standards

I saw a couple of questions that are a bit similar to my question but most of them are about a specific language or unanswered.

I am looking for a application/script that allows me to apply our coding standards to the code we commit to SVN (it is going to be a pre-commit SVN hook on our UNIX system(s)). There are a couple of things out there (php-beautifier and a couple of online things) but I can't really find anything that is used professionally and is capable of formatting multiple languages. I was just wondering if any of you are using something that is capable of doing this. And if so, what are you using?

I'm looking for an application that at least can process PHP, JavaScript, jQuery and HTML. The more the better of course. Also, being able to define the rules myself is a must.